# Using JsonPath from scala to extract full field : value list

Tags: scala, jsonpath

I'm trying to get a fully qualified set of path : value pairs from a json document.

i.e. given

```
{"a":"b", "c":{"d":3"}}
```

I'd like

```
a :: "b"
c.d :: 3
```

or something spiritually similar. There appears to be a java library which claims to do exactly that:

```
import $ivy.`com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.6.0`
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration
import com.jayway.jsonpath.Option
import com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath._

val conf = com.jayway.jsonpath.Configuration.defaultConfiguration();
val pathList = using(conf).parse("""{"a":"b", "c":{"d":3}}""")
val arg = pathList.read("$..id")
```

I get this error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: net.minidev.json.JSONArray cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$
    at repl.MdocSession$App.<init>(json test.worksheet.sc:38)
    at repl.MdocSession$.app(json test.worksheet.sc:3)
```

Any ideas out there?

Comment: If you want to code in Scala, there several json lib that are way better/more idiomatic ... Duckduckgo is your friend

Answer (score 0):

```
val arg = pathList.read[net.minidev.json.JSONArray]("$..*")
```

Needed a cast...